# Microsoft Intune Graph API to get application installed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

How to get applications installed on a particular device in intune with graph api.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to a specific Intune Graph API that can get applications installed on a particular device, you should be able to use the mobileAppInstallStatus resource type.

The following example shows how you can determine whether an application is installed on a user's device: For more info - [Using the Microsoft Graph API for Intune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-graph-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#using-the-microsoft-graph-api-for-intune).

Get from Azure Active Directory a list of devices registered to a user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/users/{user}/ownedDevices
```

Then view the list of applications for your tenant:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps
```

Take the ID from the application and determine the installation state for the application (and therefore user):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{id}/deviceStatuses/
```